# How to sum the duplicates in coo matrix efficiently in fortran?

Tags: sparse-matrix, finite-element-analysis

I have a sparse matrix in the coo format obtained from finite element assembly. It has many duplicate entries in the triplet format. I want to sum them up efficiently using Fortran. I went through the sparse kit package but I didn't find a subroutine that does this job. Any suggestions on how to achieve this efficiently? thanks.

Comment: which sparse kit are you using?

Comment: Hi @epsi1on, I am using sparsekit2 by saad. I didn't find any routine for removing duplicates from a coo matrix. Is it embedded in any other subroutine?

Comment: are you sure that the sparsekit2 do not handle duplicates when it convert COO format to CSR format?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your kit, but in the Python implementation, this summing is done as part of the conversion to `csr` format.  The `coo` entries are sorted, by row, and within that by column.  That puts duplicates next to each other.

Comment: I need something in fortran.